# How to view head columns of several data frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to view the first few columns of several data frames using a for loop?

Here is what I tried:

```
DF_List = (df1, df2, df3)
for DF in DF_List:
    print DF.head()
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-18-bed47d1fdce7>", line 6
print DF.head()
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried:
    DF_List = (df1, df2, df3)
    for DF in DF_List:
    DF.head()

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Note: This question is not a duplicate of the question involving the print function, because it is not dependent on the "print"- see second attempt within the code.

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: Try print(df.head()) instead. Currently you have capital letters according to error message. Also, in Python 3 it is print()

Comment: @ALollz python 3

Comment: @user3212593 The capital letter are consistent with my code- I just changed them for the example- edited accordingly. I tried your suggestion, but still getting an error, as follows:        
for df in df_List:
    print(df.head())                                                                                
    AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: @arkadiy Something is wrong with the object you are passing to the loop then. Because as the error says, it's a function. You should check what objects you have in your tuple.

Comment: @user3212593 thank you! you are right.